# Dynamically figure source of iFrame with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to create a program on my server that enables me to pull information from different websites. It's already written in PHP and works perfectly. I gather this information from an iframe on one of my pages. When I use the original page that was loaded by the php script in the iframe, everything works fine. But, if I click on a link inside of the iframe, the `src` is different and I don't know how to access it. How do I figure out the *NEW* `src` of the `<iframe>` with jQuery? I searched this site and can't find a good answer to this. Below is an example of my code:

the PHP:

```
<?php
  $link = $_POST['link'];
?>
  <div id="button">Button</div>
  <iframe src="<? echo $link;?>"></iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="something.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#button').click(function()
   {
     //alert iframe src
   });
  </script>
```

EDIT:

I current have this running, and it only alerts the original `src` when I click a link in the `<iframe>`. I'm needing it to alert the *NEW* `src` of the `<iframe>`.

```
<iframe id="blog_iframe" onload="iframeLoader();" height="600px" width="98%" src="<? echo $url;?>" scrolling="auto">
  <p>Your current browser does not support iFrames. Please use a different browser</p>
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function iframeLoader()
  {
    alert($('iframe').attr("src"));
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **.attr()**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    //alert iframe src
    alert( $("iframe").attr("src") );
});
```

** EDIT **

According to Edited question.

You're actually trying to get **src** of **<a>** tag inside of **<iframe>** tag

Try this

```
alert( $("iframe").contents().find("a").attr("href") );
```

Comment: Why don't you do **alert("<?php echo $link; ?>");**

Comment: because I'm trying to figure the new url (ie. if I were to click a link inside of the iframe, it would load a new page in the iframe.) I'm needing the new URL.

Comment: @Cod-nerd Or Try **alert( $(this).siblings("iframe").attr("src") );** inside of **$('#button').click(function() { });**

Comment: @Cod-nerd Also make sure.. If you have multiple buttons then you should not use **id** but **class**.

Comment: It's only one button. I'm getting it to alert everytime I click a link in the iFrame. But, it's just giving me the original src. I'll edit my question to show.

Comment: Nada. I'm trying to look at possibly doing something with a .click() function for a link clicked in an iframe (ie `$('iframe a').click(function(){alert($(this).attr("href");});`

Comment: @Cod-nerd Your code showing none of dynamically changing iframe src. Also if you were not talking about "a" tags inside of "iframe" tags. I don't get your question. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the current url of the iframe. If I click a link in the iframe, the page changes. I want that pages url.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var iFrameSrc = $("iframe").attr('src');
```